# How to output variables and values defined in a shell file

Tags: shell

I want to print out all the variables defined in the file (**not environment variables**), so that I can quickly locate the error. I thought of printing through `echo`, but this is not friendly, is there any easy way to achieve this?
For example is as follow:

```
var1=${VAR1:-"test1"}
var2=${VAR2:-"test2"}
var3=${VAR1:-"test3"}
var4=${VAR1:-"test4"}

print like below:
var1=test1
var2=modify // modified by environment var
var3=test3
var4=test4
```

I really appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 0):

In Bash you can:

```
# List all variables to a file named before
declare -p > before
# source the file
. the_file
# list all variables to a file named after
declare -p > after
# difference between variables before and after sourcing the file
diff before after
```

You can manipulate with `env -i bash -c` to get a clean environment.

The other way is just to write a parser for your file. Simple `sed 's/=.*//' the_file` will give you a list of all variable definitions.